# Adding a resized image to a frame

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, photoimage

so I'm resizing an image and adding it to a frame called playingSpace.
Here's that piece of code :

```
# Opening up the image file
img = Image.open("images/gameBoard_pic.jpg")

# Resizing the image 
resized_im = img.resize((50,50))

# Making the resized image into a photoimage
final_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_im)

# Adding the image to a label widet
label = Label(playingSpace,image = final_img)

# Putting the label widget on frame
label.pack()

# Putting the frame on window
playingSpace.pack()
```

Now I keep on getting this error: _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage7" doesn't exist.

I've tried swapping in another image and I still get the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here, and please provide a complete [mre] including all imports.